# Dual monitor started to flicker after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, multiple-monitors, video

I am running dual monitor setup (in mirror mode) on ubuntu. Right after upgrade to 16.04, I am experiencing issues with flickering (image on/off) on second screen (which is LGD LED TV), specifically when playing full screen video in browser (no matter if Chrome or Firefox). Every other minute this happens even if no video is playing, but once video is played, it happens every few seconds. I supposed it could be because of cable, so I have tried antother, but issue persists. Since this started right after upgrade to 16.04, I think it could be software or driver issue. It happens also when only TV is connected to PC. Please do you have any tips what to try, I am unable to get it working. Maybe I should somehow downgrade back to 54.10? My video chip is Intel HD Graphics 2500.

Comment: When you upgraded to 16.04, did you actually do an upgrade from within 15.10, or a fresh install with a 16.04 ISO file? The reason I ask is that if you did an upgrade, it's *possible* that a fresh install of 16.04 would work better. In any case, I wouldn't recommend going back to 15.10, because it will stop receiving security updates next month.

Comment: I did an upgrade from within 15.10... I' d rather live without security updates for a while than with flickering screen :)

Comment: Strange that it never happens when running video in VLC or SMplayer, even if it this full hd.

Comment: Does it only happen with Flash-based videos, or all videos in a web browser?

Comment: Hmm I have tested it now and it seems to be flash related. But strange is that it also always happen when I open unity dash - everytime. Really confusing...

Comment: Even more interesting is that when I reduce resolution of both monitors from 1920x1080 to 1280x1024, blinking stops immediately...

Comment: Interesting. i don't have an answer for you, but if you decide to do a fresh install, I'd recommend trying a fresh install of 16.04 to see if the problem still occurs. (You'd have to do a fresh install anyway to downgrade to 15.10, so trying out 16.04 first wouldn't take too much more time or effort)

Comment: Only the solution that works for me is to revert back to an old kernel  3.16.0-25. All the newer are kinda fucked up for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, only the solution I found was revert back to older kernel 4.2.xxxx. All the newer kernels I have tried are causing abovementioned troubles for me.